# Is there a way to put multiple arguments in to input() in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

For example, in `print()` you can do `print('String', variable, 'another string')` and it will print all three arguments. Is there a way to do something like this `input('String', variable, 'another string')` and have it print the prompt the way `print()` would?

Comment: No: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input. You can of course simply concatenate those values into one string…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string interpolation:

```
k = 1
v = "house"
c = "yep."

input(f"Do you own {k} {v}? If so, answer {c}")
```

for a prompt of:

```
Do you own 1 house? If so, answer yep.
```

Alternativly use old style string formating for the same output:

```
input ("Do you own {} {}? If so, answer {}".format( k,v,c ))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` function doesn't support multiple arguments. But you can wrap it and make your own.

```
>>> def multi_input(*args):
...     return input(' '.join(args))
... 
>>> var = 'your'
>>> multi_input('what is', var, 'name :')
what is your name :Shiplu
'Shiplu'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `end` parameter of `print()` and use `input()` without any, e.g.:

```
print('a', 'b', 'c', end='')
input()
```